# Send payment to different email address not working

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to send the payment using Express Checkout and setting a different email using

```
$sellerDetails = new SellerDetailsType();
$sellerDetails->PayPalAccountID = 'someone-elses@email.com';
$paymentDetails->SellerDetails = $sellerDetails;
```

Although the page shows the someone-elses@email.com, the payment goes to the account making the ExpressCheckout call.

Is there an alternative for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Forgot to set

```
$sellerDetails = new SellerDetailsType();
$sellerDetails->PayPalAccountID = 'someone-elses@email.com';
$paymentDetails->SellerDetails = $sellerDetails;
```

before

```
$DoECResponse = $paypalService->DoExpressCheckoutPayment($DoECReq);
```